# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables table1 and table2
table1 has id and name and table2 has id,instance(foreign key fromtable1),hostname1 and hostname2 feilds.

creating table1

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE table1 (
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> name VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
```

when i am trying to create table2 with foreign key it throws me the error

```
"ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `databasename`.`table2` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")"
```

the code is

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE table2(
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> instance VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> hostname1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> hostname2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> CONSTRAINT `fk_name`
    -> FOREIGN KEY(instance) REFERENCES table1(name)
    -> ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    -> );
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: afaik you can't (or at least really, really shouldn't) reference a column that isn't unique or a primary key.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

FK should references PK or UNIQUE field.

you can make table2 (instance) to be same type as table1 primary key (INT) and reference to table1(id).

or if you must references name
so table1(name) should be UNIQUE

Comment: i want to use name as foreign key and not id, how can i make name unique?

Comment: `mysql> CREATE TABLE table1 (

    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    -> name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE  

    -> ); `

Answer (score 0):

`name VARCHAR(50)` is `nullable` in table1 while it's `not null` in table2.

`instance` maps to `name` which is not null

```
 -> instance VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```